# Replacing all negative values in certain columns by another value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

Suppose I have four successively arranged columns as a part of a data frame and I want to replace all the negative values in these 4 columns by another value (-5 let's say), how do I do it?

```
T1   T2  T3  T4
20   -5  4   3
85  -78  34  21
-45  22  31  75
-6   5   7  -28
```

Logically, I was hoping this would work. But, it doesn't.

```
for i in df.iloc[:,df.columns.get_loc("T1"):df.columns.get_loc("T1")+4]<0:
    for j in df[i]:
        if j<0:
            j=-5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `indexing` by applying a condition statement.

```
cols = ['T1','T2','T3','T4']
df[df[cols] < 0] = -5
```

Output

```
In [35]: df
Out[35]:
     T1  T2  T3  T4
  0  20  -5   4   3
  1  85  -5  34  21
  2  -5  22  31  75
  3  -5   5   7  -5
```

In your example you're just replacing the value of variable. You need to replace one cell's value using `at` method.

```
for i in df.iloc[:,df.columns.get_loc("T1"):df.columns.get_loc("T1")+4]<0:
for index, j in enumerate(df[i]):
    if j<0:
        df.at[index, i] = -5
```

Comment: I edited my question. My data frame has 200+ columns and I want to edit only 4/5 columns arranged successively.

Comment: Thanks! This is really simple! Just wondering, though. Why doesn't it work when I write it out the way I did?

Comment: @hegdep, because in your example you just replace the value of variable. You can use `at` method in order to update the cell value. Have a look to updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) - for all columns:

```
df = df.mask(df < 0, -5)
```

Or if need specify columns:

```
cols = ['T1','T2','T3','T4']
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df[cols] < 0, -5)
print (df)
   T1  T2  T3  T4
0  20  -5   4   3
1  85  -5  34  21
2  -5  22  31  75
3  -5   5   7  -5
```

With similar approach with select by positions like in question:

```
pos = df.columns.get_loc("T1")
df.iloc[:,pos:pos+4] = df.iloc[:,pos:pos+4].mask(df < 0, -5)
```

EDIT:

Looping solutions in pandas are not recommended, if [exist vectorized solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871316/2901002), because slow.

But it is possible, your code should be change with [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) and [`iteritems`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html):

```
for i, row in df.iloc[:,df.columns.get_loc("T1"):df.columns.get_loc("T1")+4].iterrows():
    for j,k in row.iteritems():
        if k < 0:
            df.loc[i, j] = -5
print (df)
   T1  T2  T3  T4
0  20  -5   4   3
1  85  -5  34  21
2  -5  22  31  75
3  -5   5   7  -5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use indexing:

```
c = ['T1','T2','T3','T4']
df[df[c] < 0] = -5
```

Or [`clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html):

```
In [47]: df[c].clip(lower=-5)
Out[47]:
   T1  T2  T3  T4
0  20  -5   4   3
1  85  -5  34  21
2  -5  22  31  75
3  -5   5   7  -5
```

Comment: I edited my question. My data frame has 200+ columns and I want to edit only 4/5 columns arranged successively.